# How to implement business logic in Faye? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, faye

I have Rack Faye application on Thin server and i have some logic on every faye client handshake/subscribe/disconnect.

This logic requires data storage in DB, some calculations and publishing messages back to some channels.

Where and how should one implement such stuff to avoid blocking main Faye thread with extensions?

Answer (score 1):

author of Faye here. Depends what DB you're talking to, but in general you should use a non-blocking (i.e. based on EventMachine's TCP stack) database client. This means the extension will return quickly (assuming you're not waiting on the result of the DB call to affect the incoming/outgoing message) so Faye can continue processing messages while the DB call is in progress.

Comment: thanks for answer & a lot for Faye. DB is usually Postgres. You mean using EventMachine like described here http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby/clients.html ? That's the only option? 
The only problem i found with this that i cannot subscribe to '/meta/*' channel and => can't get full control over connected clients.